# Function displaying an odd cout

Tags: c++, function, debugging, cout

I'm trying to make sure that my code works correctly so I am having my bool functions print the true or false that they are returning. However, my function checkColSum which checks to see if every column in my parallel array adds up to 15 is printing three trues and a false when I enter the numbers:

4 9 2
3 5 7
8 1 6

I would really appreciate any help regarding this issue. I just can't seem to figure out what's going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Global constants 
const int ROWS = 3;  // The number of rows in the array
const int COLS = 3;  // The number of columns in the array
const int MIN = 1;  // The value of the smallest number
const int MAX = 9;  // The value of the largest number

// Function prototypes
bool isMagicSquare(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size);
bool checkRange(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size, int min, int max);
bool checkUnique(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size);
bool checkRowSum(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size);
bool checkColSum(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size);
bool checkDiagSum(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size);
void fillArray(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size);
void showArray(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size);

int main()
{

    /* Define a Lo Shu Magic Square using 3 parallel arrays corresponding         to each row of the grid */
    int magicArrayRow1[COLS], magicArrayRow2[COLS], magicArrayRow3[COLS];
    // Your code goes here
    int repeat = 1;

    while (repeat == 1) {
        fillArray(magicArrayRow1, magicArrayRow2, magicArrayRow3, 3);
        showArray(magicArrayRow1, magicArrayRow2, magicArrayRow3, 3);

        /*TESTING DELETE BEFORE TURNING IN*/
        checkRange(magicArrayRow1, magicArrayRow2, magicArrayRow3, 3, 1, 9); //works
        cout << endl;
        checkUnique(magicArrayRow1, magicArrayRow2, magicArrayRow3, 3); //doesnt work
        cout << endl;
        checkRowSum(magicArrayRow1, magicArrayRow2, magicArrayRow3, 3);//works
        cout << endl;
        checkColSum(magicArrayRow1, magicArrayRow2, magicArrayRow3, 3); //works?? maybe??

        /*TESTING DELETE BEFORE TURNING IN*/

        if (isMagicSquare(magicArrayRow1, magicArrayRow2, magicArrayRow3, 3) == true) {
            cout << endl << "This is a Lo Shu magic square.";
        }
        else {
            cout << endl << "This is not a Lo Shu magic square.";
        }
        cout << endl << "Would you like to try again? Enter 1 for yes or 0  for no: ";
        cin >> repeat;
    }

    return 0;
}
// Function definitions go here
bool isMagicSquare(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size)
{
    bool trueFalse = false;
    if (checkRange(arrayRow1, arrayRow2, arrayRow3, 3, 1, 9) == true && checkUnique(arrayRow1, arrayRow2, arrayRow3, 3) == true) {
        if (checkRowSum(arrayRow1, arrayRow2, arrayRow3, 3) == true && checkColSum(arrayRow1, arrayRow2, arrayRow3, 3) == true) {
            if (checkDiagSum(arrayRow1, arrayRow2, arrayRow3, 3) == true) {
                trueFalse = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return trueFalse;
}

bool checkRange(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size, int min, int max)
{
    bool inRange = true;
    int count = 0;

    while (inRange && count < size) {
        if (arrayRow1[count] < min || arrayRow1[count] > max) {
            inRange = false;
        }
        count++;
    }

    while (inRange && count < size) {
        if (arrayRow2[count] < min || arrayRow2[count] > max) {
            inRange = false;
        }
        count++;
    }

    while (inRange && count < size) {
        if (arrayRow3[count] < min || arrayRow3[count] > max) {
            inRange = false;
        }
        count++;
    }

    if (inRange == true) {// TEST
        cout << "true";
    }
    if(inRange == false) {
        cout << "false";
    }
    return inRange;
}

bool checkUnique(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size)
{
    bool isUnique = false;
    int count = 0;

    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    int four = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int six = 0;
    int seven = 0;
    int eight = 0;
    int nine = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    { //checks row 1
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 1) { //checks if row one contains the value 1 in any position
            one++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 2) {
            two++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 3) {
            three++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 4) {
            four++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 5) {
            five++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 6) {
            six++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 7) {
            seven++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 8) {
            eight++;
        }
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 9) {
            nine++;
        }


    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //checks row 2
        if (arrayRow1[i] == 1) { //checks if row two contains the value 1 in any position
            one++; //if the value 1 is present, a count is added
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 2) {
            two++;
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 3) {
            three++;
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 4) {
            four++;
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 5) {
            five++;
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 6) {
            six++;
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 7) {
            seven++;
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 8) {
            eight++;
        }
        if (arrayRow2[i] == 9) {
            nine++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //checks row 1
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 1) { //checks if row one contains the value 1 in any position
            one++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 2) {
            two++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 3) {
            three++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 4) {
            four++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 5) {
            five++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 6) {
            six++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 7) {
            seven++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 8) {
            eight++;
        }
        if (arrayRow3[i] == 9) {
            nine++;
        }
    }

    if (one == 1 && two == 1 && three == 1 && four == 1 && five == 1 && six == 1 && seven == 1 && eight == 1 && nine == 1) { // checks that every variable counting the repition of numbers 1-9 in the arrays is equal to one
        isUnique = true;
        cout << "True";
    }
    if (one != 1 || two != 1 || three != 1 || four != 1 || five != 1 || six != 1 || seven != 1 || eight != 1 || nine != 1) {

        isUnique = false;
        cout << "False";
    }

    return isUnique;
}

bool checkRowSum(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size)
{
    bool magicSquare = true; //variable declares whether it is a magic square or not
    int sumRow1 = 0; //sum of row1
    int sumRow2 = 0; //sum of row2
    int sumRow3 = 0; //sum of row3

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sumRow1 += arrayrow1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sumRow2 += arrayrow2[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sumRow3 += arrayrow3[i];
    }

    if (sumRow1 == 15 && sumRow2 == 15 && sumRow3 == 15) {
        magicSquare = true;
        cout << "true";
    }
    else {
        magicSquare = false;
        cout << "false";
    }

    return magicSquare;
}

bool checkColSum(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size)
{
    bool magicSquare = false;

    int sumCol1 = 0;
    int sumCol2 = 0;
    int sumCol3 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //iterates through the array
        if (i == 0) { //when i equals 1
            sumCol1 += arrayrow1[i]; 
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            sumCol2 += arrayrow2[i];
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            sumCol3 += arrayrow3[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            sumCol1 += arrayrow3[i];
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            sumCol2 += arrayrow1[i];
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            sumCol3 += arrayrow2[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            sumCol1 += arrayrow2[i];
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            sumCol2 += arrayrow3[i];
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            sumCol3 += arrayrow1[i];
        }
    }

    if (sumCol1 == 15 && sumCol2 == 15 && sumCol3 == 15) {
        magicSquare = true;
        cout << "true";
    }
    else {
        magicSquare = false;
    }


    return magicSquare;
}

bool checkDiagSum(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size)
{
    bool magicSquare = true;
    int sumDiag1 = 0;
    int sumDiag2 = 0;

    sumDiag1 = arrayrow1[0] + arrayrow2[1] + arrayrow3[2];
    sumDiag2 = arrayrow1[3] + arrayrow2[1] + arrayrow3[0];

    if (sumDiag1 == 15 && sumDiag2 == 15) {
        magicSquare = true;
        cout << "true";
    }
    else {
        magicSquare = false;
        cout << "false";
    }

    return magicSquare;
}

void fillArray(int arrayRow1[], int arrayRow2[], int arrayRow3[], int size)
{
    int userInput;

    //fills row 1
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //iterates according to int size which is the number of columns/rows
        cout << "Enter the number for row 1, column " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> userInput;
        arrayRow1[i] = userInput;
        cout << endl;
    }

    //fills row 2
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
        cout << "Enter the number for row 2, column " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> userInput;
        arrayRow2[i] = userInput;
        cout << endl;
    }

    //fills row 3
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number for row 3, column " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> userInput;
        arrayRow3[i] = userInput;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void showArray(int arrayrow1[], int arrayrow2[], int arrayrow3[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //displays row 1
        cout << arrayrow1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl; //moves down one row

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //displays row 2
        cout << arrayrow2[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl; //moves down one row

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //displays row 3
        cout << arrayrow3[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl; //moves down one row
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)